# VBA - error "Constant expression require "

Tags: vba, constants, expression

I am doing the lab with 2 dimensions array in VBA, but got the issue as my photo attached. Could you please help assist if any error ? Any assist will be very appriciated.
this is my code :

```
        Sub read_data()
     
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12")
       total_row = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12").Rows.Count
       total_col = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12").Columns.Count
        Dim arr2(total_row, total_col)
        
        arr2 = rng
        For i = 0 To total_row
            For j = 0 To total_col
                Debug.Print i, j, arr2(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

End Sub
```

the error as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' closest to the source code
Sub read_data()
     
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12")
    total_row = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12").Rows.Count
    total_col = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12").Columns.Count
    Dim arr2    ' remove (total_row, total_col)
    
    arr2 = rng
    For i = 1 To total_row      '1 instead 0
        For j = 1 To total_col  '1 instead 0
            Debug.Print i, j, arr2(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

'slightly improved

Sub read_data2()
    Dim arr2 As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    
    With Sheet1.Range("C8:G12")
        arr2 = .Value
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Debug.Print i, j, arr2(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the system require you use `constant variable` when you want the determine the size of the array, however you do not need to pre-set the size of the array, as when you declare an `Range value` as array, it will auto set the size of the array.

In addition, to find the length of the array, it will be better to use `Lbound & Ubound` of array, here is the code that work and shorter also:

```
Sub read_data()
Dim total_col As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim arr2

total_col = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12").Columns.Count
arr2 = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12")

For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
    For j = 1 To total_col
        Debug.Print arr2(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

**Reference** (a constant variable cannot be changed value during the execution once it was declared as the beginning):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-constants

Answer (score 0):

You can put the values from the range directly into the array, then use `LBound` and `UBound` in the loops to get the lower/upper limits for each dimension.

```vb
Sub read_data()
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim idxRow As Long  
Dim idxCol As Long

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("C8:G12")
    arr2 = rng.Value
     
    For idxRow = LBound(arr2,1) To UBound(arr2,1)
        For idxCol = LBound(arr2,2) To UBound(arr2,2)
            Debug.Print idxRow, idxCol, arr2(idxRow, idxCol)
        Next idxCol
    Next idxRow

End Sub
```